# Create the .cspkg and the .cscfg files to upload into Azure

Tags: php, upload, azure

I opened more topic here to solve my uploading problem but still nothing (not the answers, these were helpful) so I think the problem is at me!

So I wrote a little php program but after I create and upload the .cspkg and .cscfg files into Azure I get error. On localhost everything is good. I decided to reinstall all of my computer and sdk's but it takes so long time therefor I ask you a bit favour!

I send you my php files then you create the the .cspkg and .cscfg files and I upload it to my azure account and if it's OK, I can make sure of that the error is guaranteed to me...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please outline what error you are receiving? Is it that you are browsing to the site and receiving a 500 server error or does this error get surfaced in the management portal?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are doing however I would like to provide your the correct way to use PHP with Azure:

Step 1: please have some time to study how Azure Interoperability team provided PHP SDK for Azure here:
http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php

Step 2: Please download the PHP SDK for Windows Azure:
http://phpazure.codeplex.com/releases/view/78020

Step 3: Visit the SDK related documentation:
http://phpazure.codeplex.com/documentation

Above info will guide you through how to get it working. If you still need help for PHP issue, open an incident with Windows Azure Support Team using link below to get expert 1:1 assistance:
https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

[Addition]
If you follow the link below, in the step 4 you were given the script to create ServiceDefinition.csdef using your paplication project folder details: 
http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/packaging-applications

Once you have your project folder set as described in above link and have ServiceDefinition.csdef you can full step 5 to generate the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg also.

Comment: thank you your reply! I already had read the documents but still I have no idea why I get error thats why I want to start all over again (start with uninstall windows7) but it is a long process... Therefore I want to search anybody to create me the cspkg, cscfg files from my php files, and following this everything is good - I get 100% guarantee that the problem has at me - than I have to start reinstall and install all over again because something went wrong :(

Comment: The problem is that no one knows your application folder architecture, role name etc so a generic CSCFG and CSDEF will not work. You will have to create it based on your application architecture. I have included info to create Service Definition and Service Configuration in my above post in "Addition" section.